# RxJava publish intervalRange ticks

Tags: rx-java2

I have a countdown timer that I need to observe it's time ticks from multiple places.

Current implementation is:

```
fun startTimer(sleepSeconds: Long) {

    sleepTimer = Observable.intervalRange(1, sleepSeconds, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({

               // need to emit values

            }, {
                Log.d(TAG, it.message)
            }, {
                releaseStuff()
            })
}
```

How to implement it so it emits time ticks?

Comment: The answer is in the title: `publish()`, and possibly with `autoConnect()` too.

Comment: @akarnokd Not sure how this can be used in my case, but i will research that option